# Separate a dataframe rows based on most recent updated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df with names `Mark`,`Luke`,`Leno` with two columns `a` and `b`.
I want the most recent updated row for each names.

df

```
                        a       b

                    0   Mark    120
                    1   Luke    25
                    2   Leno    65
                    3   Mark    21
                    4   Mark    100
                    5   Luke    57
                    6   Luke    54
                    7   Mark    7
                    8   Leno    98
                    9   Leno    79
                    10  Mark   100
```

Resultant Output:

```
                        a       b

                    10   Mark    100
                     6   Luke    54
                     9   Leno    79
```

Comment: Found the sountion, Any other ways 
`df = df.drop_duplicates('a', keep='last')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `drop_duplicates` keeping the last appearance.

```
df_last_appearance = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["a"], keep="last")
```